# Error: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1

Tags: android, compilation, dependencies

I tried to build my project but on the process, I get this error message;

Error: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1

Error: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1

Error: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1

Error: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1

Its very annoying and I've tried my best to fix it but yet, the error message still persist.

Have anyone here experience such issue, how did you fixed it?

Comment: I just found out the main issue

Just go to your Gradle.Properties file and remove these lines of IP

systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1

systemProp.http.proxyPort=1080